# grouping fields in django form

Tags: python, django

I want to render form grouping fields. Form actually is created dynamically according to incoming dictionary

```
for f in settings.FORM_BIG_FIELDS:
        self.fields[f['id']] = eval(f['type'])(label=f['label'], required=f.get('required', True))
        self.fields[f['id']].groupp = f.get('group', 1)
```

groupp attribute means appropriate group, then I try to render it like

```
{% regroup form.fields.values by groupp as field_group %}
    {% for group in field_group %}
    <div class="group_{{ group.grouper }}">
            {% for field in group.list %}
            <p>
                {{ field.all }}
                {{ field }}
            </p>
            {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

But as output I get the following

```
<django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0xb527388c>
<django.forms.fields.IntegerField object at 0xb52738ec>
<django.forms.fields.ChoiceField object at 0xb527394c>
```

I have read that these are not the same as BoundField object. How to render fields or is there any other better approaches to group fields?

Comment: You need fieldsets man:https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-form-utils

Comment: This is one of the possible solutions, but I want to go without additional libraries and use only native ones. Actually, I managed to divide them by groups, however cannot render field to HTML.

Comment: I am trying to use form-utils. Is there any way to create fieldsets dynamically? The problem is that I cannot see fields attribute inside class Meta, and hence cannot regroup them for fieldsets. The structure I got is Ok, but it cannot see neigher self.fields nor fields.

Comment: If you want it to be dynamic then do it before you declare Meta. Dynamic forms are hard with django and in cases where i have needed to do it like that i have wrapped class into function, that creates the Meta data for class, then declares the class and in the end returns form class.

Comment: Sounds really tough:) Could you provide an example and sample code?

Comment: def get_form(some, variables):
   this = that
   fields = [something for something in something else]
   class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
      class Meta:
          model = this
          fields = fields

    return SomeForm

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want use any additional libraries, then the most easy solution is to render them manually, i would say. Otherwise you will just spend alot of time repeating the functionality of the library i copied as comment to your post.

There is always the case that things should be DRY. But we build websites for the users and user cares little about how the form rendering in template is done. For this reason we have often created form templates manually like this:

```
<div class="something">
{{ form.fieldname.label_tag }}{{ form.fieldname }}
</div>
```

Easyest way to organise it saving you some time. And in my opinion it is not that bad either, since this is not very common when you need fields organised by fieldsets.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is rather old, but I am sure there are still people who can benefit from a simple solution:

Say you have a group name and list of members.  You can define a self.fieldset in your form's **init** to be a dictionary of {'group_1': ['member_1', 'member_2', ... ], ... }.  Once you attach this to the form, you can pass it to views and from there to the template:

## In forms.py:

```
class MyForm:
    def __init__(self, current_user, *args, **kwargs):    
        super(YourForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.field['group'].queryset = Group.objects.filter(user = current_user)
        ...
```

## In views.py:

```
form = self.Form(current_user)
the_fieldsets = form.fieldset

c = {'form': search_form,
     'fieldsets':  the_fieldsets }
```

## In your template:

```
{% for field in form %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{field.label_tag}}</td>
                {% if field.name == 'group' %}
                <td>

                    <select id='{{field.id}}' name='{{field.name}}'>
                        {% for k,v in fieldsets.items %}
                        <optgroup label = {{k.name}}>
                            {% for val in v %}
                                <option name='{{val}} value = {{val.id}}> {{val.name}} </option>  # Note that the select needs to return 'id', so value has to be {{val.id}}
                            {% endfor %}
                        </optgroup>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                </td>                       
                {% else %}
                    <td>{{field}}</td>
                {% endif %}

                <td>{{field.help_text}}</td>
                <td>{{field.errors}}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The secret is to use :

```
self[name]
```

in the form object. So you can use it in any dictionary like :

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__( *args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['field01'] = forms.IntegerField()
    self.groupe1 = {'foo' : self['field01']}
```

and now it will render correctly in the template. But in the above code you'll also have to deal with the initial and data value of the field. But it is an other question.

Comment: Edit : after use of it : it seems there is no problem with initial and data values